# Spring - inject vavr collections

Tags: java, spring, collections, autowired, vavr

In my Spring project I use extensively collections from [vavr](http://vavr.io/) library. Sometimes I need to inject collection of beans. As far as I know Spring can only inject collections from JDK, e.g. `List`, `Set`, `Map`, etc. Is there any way to inject vavr collection? I would like to do something like this:

```
@Component
class NameResolver {

    @Autowired
    io.vavr.collection.List<NameMatcher> matchers; // how to make it work?
}
```

Comment: yes you can autowired this Collection. but it should be in maven dependencies list.

Comment: What excatly? I have vavr library on the classpath.

Comment: Then you can place your jar in Nexus repository there by you can add in maven

Comment: I do have this dependency. I fetch it from Maven Central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.0

Comment: As long as there is a list of that type as a bean available Spring will inject it. It will not inject the beans of that type automatically it will only do that for JDK collections. One workaround is to inject the normal collection and when needed wrap it in the vavr one.

Comment: That's the way I do this currently (i.e. inject JDK collection and then wrap it in vavr collection) but I was thinking there is a way to avoid this additional step

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that Spring only supports injecting JDK collections of spring beans. You can work around this with a kind of a *bridge* `@Bean` factory method in one of your `@Configuration` classes, similar to this:

```
import io.vavr.collection.List;
import java.util.Collection;

...

@Bean
public List<NameMatcher> vavrMatchers(Collection<NameMatcher> matchers) {
    return List.ofAll(matchers);
}
```

With the above, you created a vavr `List` that is also a Spring bean, so you can `@Autowire` it into other Spring beans. It saves you from wrapping at the injection site, so you only have to do it once for each collection of beans, instead of once for each `@Autowired` injection site.